# Apt Issue in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

When I run this command, its not installing the packages, as indicated on the last line below.

```
apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apache2-mpm-prefork libapache2-mod-php5
Suggested packages:
  php-pear
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apache2-mpm-worker
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2-mpm-prefork libapache2-mod-php5
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 1 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 2,836kB/2,839kB of archives. 
After this operation, 7,746kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y 
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main libapache2-mod-php5 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.10 [2,836kB]
Fetched 2,836kB in 3s (785kB/s)
Download complete and in download only mode
```

Comment: What are you trying to install?

Comment: I am trying to install libapache2-mod-php5

Comment: Its downloading the packages, but not getting installed. the packages are kept in /var/cache/apt/archives/ but not getting installed, when give apt-get install <packages name> as you see in the question its showing Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y Download complete and in download only mode

Answer (score 1):

sounds like at one time you downloaded something in download only mode like

```
apt-get install packageName –download-only
```

It failed so your apt-get -f install was fixing it.. So try to go about your usual apt usage and things should be ok

Comment: Its downloading the packages, but not getting installed. the packages are kept in /var/cache/apt/archives/ but not getting installed, when give 
apt-get install <packages name> as you see in the question its showing 
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y 
Download complete and in download only mode

Comment: in your example you are doing an apt-get -f install

Comment: Yes! After doing that the package is not getting installed, its getting stored in /var/cache/apt/archives/ but its not installing.

Comment: try going into that dir and dpkg -i packageName.deb

Comment: Showing this below error.

dpkg -i libgd2-xpm_2.0.36~rc1~dfsg-3.1ubuntu1_i386.deb
dpkg: regarding libgd2-xpm_2.0.36~rc1~dfsg-3.1ubuntu1_i386.deb containing libgd2-xpm:
 libgd2-xpm conflicts with libgd2
  libgd2-noxpm provides libgd2 and is present and installed.
dpkg: error processing libgd2-xpm_2.0.36~rc1~dfsg-3.1ubuntu1_i386.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing libgd2-xpm
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgd2-xpm_2.0.36~rc1~dfsg-3.1ubuntu1_i386.deb

Comment: Hey, Solved the issue. Thanks for the help, I removed the conflicting packages by using aptitude. Thanks for the great help Mike. :)